# app inventor 2 send data to php myadmin using php script

Tags: php, app-inventor

I am doing an assignment to send data to php myadmin database from MIT app inventor 2 through php script. I am using this code I found from youtube in MIT app inventor 2 to send customer info and also this php script.

However when the button is pressed after the information is filled up, the information is not sent into the database. Is there something that I have missed?
I tired using google and input the full url http://arduino.byethost22.com/submitcust.php?FirstName=als&LastName=sdfg&Street=asfkj&City=lkjfds&State=ca&Zip=saj&Email=dals&Phone=asdj&Recorder=admin and the data is stored in the database.

It seems that the MIT app inventor code is missing something. Would appreciate for any help you guys can offer.
The php code:
[image]
[image]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kJj8j.png (php script)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7wVo5.png (MIT app inventor code) 
Would appreciate for any help

Comment: You can compare with [this solution](https://puravidaapps.com/mysql.php). Modify the php script to return "success" or an error messge to App Inventor. Use the `Web.GotText` event to receive the result. Btw. the database is called MySQL database and not php myadmin database....

Comment: @Taifun, i tried the solution u recommended, and add echo success in the php script and use the web1.got text to display the result in a label. However it return some message saying this site requires javascript to work, please enable javascript in your browser when using the emulator.
But if i use google chrome on my computer and enter the php link, it can display success on my google tab. 
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: use a device for your tests instead of the emulator...

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see anything immediately wrong with your PHP or AI2 blocks (though I can't tell if there's actually a SPACE in that %20 replace block), so first things first: Start by making sure the Web1 URL is actually what you want it to be. Add a notifier to the project (if you don't have one already), and do a ShowAlert of the Web1.url. You say that manually entering the URL gave the expected result, so if the produced URL matches what you manually entered perfectly, then I'm lost, sorry!